# "With knowing" grammar checking AND/OR synonyms

Tags: grammar, word-choice, word-order

I have this sentence that forms a disaster for me. I know what is wrong with it but I can't find some suitable fixes.

The sentence is:

***I'm actually wondering why did the chef keep silent all that time, with knowing the slightest details about me and her boyfriend?***

1- I feel like it would be more proper for **keep silent** to be **kept silent**, but it is in a question form, so it won't fit.

2- **With knowing**, I find it improper English. So, I tried to replace it with "**With her knowing**","**despite her knowing**", and "**although knowing**". But I find them having the same problem in common.

Comment: Choose between "did keep" or "kept", and drop the "with".

Comment: With **slightest** do you mean to suggest that she knew almost nothing, or that she knew even the smallest details?

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo I mean by it that she knew the smallest details. But I think I use it wrong after reading the answers.

Comment: Is the boyfriend the chef's boyfriend or the boyfriend of a different person, a woman? Is the chef a woman?

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo The boyfriend is the chef's boyfriend, and the chef is a woman.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a native American speaker, I'd suggest:

**I'm actually wondering why the chef kept silent all that time while knowing every detail about me and her boyfriend.**

*or*

**I'm actually wondering, "Why did the chef keep silent all that time, knowing every tiny detail about me and her boyfriend?"**

- Each of those are statements, not questions. They state that I am wondering something.
- I wouldn't use "the slightest" that way. I either use it in a negative sense: "*I haven't the slightest idea*" or as a threshold: "*Press the button if he makes the slightest move.*" I offer a couple alternatives in the examples above.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions, with those two, I would fix a lot of dialogs at my story. I just want to know what do you mean by "Threshold"? Does it mean "a start of something"?

Answer (score 2):

@user3169 Covered the first part pretty well. You can leave it as is, or drop the *did* and use:

> I'm actually wondering why the chef kept silent all that time...

For the second part, *despite* sounds the best to me. The others are all grammatical as far as I'm aware though.

Also, *slightest* isn't the word you're looking for here. *Slightest* means a small amount when used in a context like this, whereas you are using it to mean small details (as in, even the small details). I would go with *every detail*.

So, in conclusion we have:

> **I'm actually wondering why the chef kept silent all that time, despite knowing every detail about me and her boyfriend.**

Answer (score 2):

I'll start by pointing out some problems with the grammar:

- **Wondering why did** sounds awkward.
- **All that time** doesn't have any context. I want to ask "All *what* time?*
- ***With*** **knowing the slightest detail** is actually the opposite of a common phrase: ***without*** **knowing the slightest detail**. So, it doesn't sound quite right.

The second point may make sense if there actually is more context, but I can only go by the sentence itself.

---

I'm going to suggest a rephrasing based on what I *think* you're trying to express:

> I wonder why the chef kept silent for so long, knowing all that she did about me and her boyfriend?

This may be too much rephrasing without knowing context.

Here is a more conservative edit:

> I'm actually wondering why the chef kept silent all that time, knowing all that she did about me and her boyfriend.

Here, I removed the question mark because, unless it's dialogue, it's more of a statement as it's written than an actual question.

Comment: I didn't mean it that way. I meant that the chef knew about the romantic relationship, I and her boyfriend, had. About "that time", it is a story and this sentence is one of many, so it would be clear for the reader what time I am talking about.

Answer (score 2):

As used colloquially, **I wonder** and **I am wondering** can introduce an assertion about yourself which is complemented by a finite clause with normal (SVO) word order, or they can be used to pose a question about something and in that case they are complemented by a clause showing subject-verb inversion.

Don't worry too much about the question mark punctuation and the use of quotation marks.

I wonder why he is late.

I wonder, why is he late?

Why is he late, I wonder.

I am wondering why he is late.

I am wondering, why is he late?

Why he is late, I wonder. <sup>not idiomatic</sup>

Comment: Is "I wonder" and "I am wondering" used colloquially? And, is using colloquially in stories, a good and common thing? I'm not talking about "I'm gonna" for example. But words as "wonder". Thanks for the examples of the question mark 's issue, by the way.

Comment: **wonder**  and **wondering** are used frequently in conversation and casual contexts, rarely if ever in formal contexts.  You will hear *She wonders if the train is late* but it would be most unusual to hear *This Court wonders if you are satisfied with the representation your attorneys have given you.*